# Ember element/component removal behaves unexpectedly [twiddle provided]

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components

Basically Im trying to add visualilzation to a delete action.

And the code im using:

```
    {{#each wrappedRecords as |record|}}
        {{#fade-element}}
                {{record.name}}
                <span class="remove" {{action "removeRecord" record}}></span>
            </span>
        {{/fade-element}}
    {{/each}}
```

So the removeRecord action is being triggered and a **record** is removed from **wrappedRecords**

And now in my *fade-element* component wrapper. I catch component destroy in `willDestroyElement` hook.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
       willDestroyElement : function () {
            var clone = this.$().clone();
            clone.insertAfter(this.$());
            clone.fadeOut();
        },
});
```

And it does not work however when i replace:

`clone.insertAfter(this.$());` with `clone.insertAfter(this.$().parent());`

It does work but then a new problem comes up. E.g:

I have 2 items and i try to remove the first it would look like this

X1 (to delete) X2 (second element) X1 (Clone that was appeneded to parent)

Link to live demo

https://ember-twiddle.com/ef8c4bcdcd8d2eb5b5c4?openFiles=fade-element.component.js%2Cfade-element.template.hbs

Comment: Would it be possible to make an Ember Twiddle? https://ember-twiddle.com

Comment: @Gaurav Yeh, I'll make it 2morrow

Comment: @Gaurav https://ember-twiddle.com/ef8c4bcdcd8d2eb5b5c4?openFiles=fade-element.component.js%2Cfade-element.template.hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things:

1. The parent contains the X2, so naturally inserting an element after the parent will not work.
2. The view is about to be torn down, so you can't use it, and the parent view will rerender, so you can't put the element inside it and expect it to stick.

The solution is

1. Wait until after the rerender takes place using Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', ...). To learn more about the Ember Run Loop, see https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/applications/run-loop/
2. Save a reference to the previous element so that you know where you can place the clone.

See https://ember-twiddle.com/966c8c6d364e0f631c0b?openFiles=fade-element.component.js%2Cfade-element.template.hbs for the solution as a twiddle.

Comment: Holy sh*t you actually managed to make it work. Tried for hours and no success. Thanks so much man! This is what i came up last :D https://gist.github.com/kristjanreinhold/b802a5421e2608d48681